# Как настроить SSH-ключ для виртуальной машины на c9.io и github.com, чтобы он не сбрасывался на следующий день?

Tags: git, github

Здравствуйте!

У меня непонятная проблема с командой `git push` на виртуальных машинах `c9.io`, на которых находятся клоны моих репозиториев с `github.com`. Таких машин у меня набралось аж три штуки и на всех одна и та же проблема.

При попытке внести изменения в репозиторий:

```
git push
```

я получаю следующую ошибку:

> ERROR: Permission to cardinalkeeper/database.git denied to khusamov.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Далее приходится создавать новый ключ утилитой `ssh-keygen`. Старый ключ из настроек репозитория удаляю, новый загружаю. Командую `git push` и все изменения вносятся в репозиторий.

А на следующий день, та же ошибка. То есть снова нет доступа в репозиторий. Снова приходится создавать ключ. И так уже раз N (N стремится к бесконечности) делал.

Как избавиться от этого белого бычка?

### Уточнения:

- Виртуальная машина, откуда делается push, находится на c9.io.
- Таких "глючных" репозиториев набралось аж трое.
- Виртуальные машины замораживаются на 7 сутки, если нет действий.
- Техподдержка гитхаба пытается помочь, но пока безрезультатно.
- В общем уже не знаю куда копать.
- С битбукетом таких проблем нет.

Все что описано на странице https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/ опробовал, не помогает. Ключ вроде работает, но гитхаб push не принимает.

Как мне сказали: "пушить невозможно - странно, т.к. github успешно распознаёт ваш ключ, и то что он привязан к пользователю khusamov".

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена https://toster.ru/q/337244

Техподдержка c9.io ответила.
Оказывается проблема в том, что файл id_rsa постоянно перезаписывается.

https://community.c9.io/t/which-program-can-spontaneously-change-id-rsa-file/11504

cloud9 puts an autogenerated ssh key into `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
You can add that to github, or put your key into `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github`, and add a config like

~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Port 22
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```